# Divs move around when resizing/zooming-in/out page

Tags: html, css, resize

I know this question has been asked a fair amount of times, but none of the solutions I found worked for me. I have this website I am making, and the div elements move around when I zoom-in and zoom-out the webpage. Here is the HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>    
    <head>
        <!-- Header -->
        <center>
            <img src="http://i1349.photobucket.com/albums/p742/lucasgame13/header_zps8f446598.png" alt="Shawn&amp;LucasWeb">
        </center>
        <!-- Header -->
        <title>Shawn & Lucas Web Development!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>    
    <body>
        <center>
            <h1>Welcome to Shawn & Lucas Web Development!</h1>
        </center>
        <!-- Left Box -->
        <div id="leftbox">
             <h3> Info </h3>

            <p>This is a test. -</p>
            <p>- <a href="Red.html">Click here!</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <!-- End of Left Box -->
        <!-- Middle Box -->
        <div id="box">
             <h3> Menu </h3>

            <p>Navigate around the website!</p>
            <center><a href="about.html">About Us</a> 
            </center>
        </div>
        <!-- End of Middle Box -->
        <!-- Right Box -->
        <div id="rightbox">
             <h3> Menu </h3>

            <p>Navigate around the website!</p>
        </div>
        <!-- End of Right Box -->
        <footer>
            <p class="us"><font color="black"> Shawn & Lucas WEB - Custom Websites &copy; </p>
         </footer>
     </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS code is this:

```
body {
    background:#61c9f5;
}
h1 {
    color:#000000;
    font-family:"Impress BT" arial verdana;
    position:relative;
    bottom:37px;
}    
p.us {
    tetx-align:center;
    color:white;
    font:bold 400%
}

/* Middle Box */
#box {
    border-width: 0.139in;
    border-color: rgb( 75, 75, 75 );
    border-style: dashed;
    background-color: rgb( 115, 115, 115 );
    width: 309px;
    height: 296px;
    z-index: 1;
    display:block;
    margin: auto auto;      
}    
#box h3 { 
    font-size:180%;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    bottom:30px;        
}    
#box p {
    position:relative;
    bottom:60px;
    text-align:center;      
}    
#box a:link, a:visited {
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#778899;
    width:120px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid black; 
}    
#box a:hover, a:active {
    background-color:#708090
}

/* End of Middle Box */

/* Left Box */ 
#leftbox {
    border-width: 0.139in;
    border-color: rgb( 75, 75, 75 );
    border-style: dashed;
    background-color: rgb( 115, 115, 115 );
    width: 309px;
    height: 296px;
    z-index: 1;
    position:absolute;
    left:70px 
}  
#leftbox h3 {
    font-size:180%;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    bottom:30px;
}
#leftbox p {
    position:relative;
    bottom:60px;
    text-align:center;
}
/* End of Left Box */

/* Right Box */
#rightbox {
    border-width: 0.139in;
    border-color: rgb( 75, 75, 75 );
    border-style: dashed;
    background-color: rgb( 115, 115, 115 );
    width: 309px;
    height: 296px;
    z-index: 1;
    position:absolute;
    top:395px;
    right:70px;     
}
/* End of Right Box */

div {                    
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

I don't have a link because it is only on my computer, but I have screenshots:

http://prntscr.com/34ypmu - Here is the normal website at 100% zoom

http://prntscr.com/34yq9w - This is how it gets when zoomed in.

I can't post more than 2 links because I don't have 10 reputation, but when it is zoomed out
the boxes go far away from each other.

I know the website isn't really a good website but it is just a test, because not any other website would work when I zoomed in. Please help! (I did try a wrapper but it didn't work)

Comment: You shouldn't put an image in the `<head>` tag and the `<center>` tag is deprecated.

Comment: It's strange. I hear about things breaking when zoomed all the time, but have never had the problem myself…

Comment: @Mathias,I know, it was my friend (We made the website together) who did it like that and I didn't change it because i didn't notice it. I fixed that but it still doesn't work.

Comment: #bjb568 I think it has to do with the positioning but I really dont know.

Comment: @Lucas I think it may be absolute/fixed positioning…

Comment: @bjb568 The middle one doesn't change (it has "display:block", "margin-left:auto" and "margin-right:auto") so its fine but the other ones move around. Do you think it has to be fixed positioning instead of absolute?

Comment: @Lucas You should not use absolute unless absolutely necessary. Use float or inline-block.

Comment: Try taking a look at this. http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/JFkYL/ You can also read up on `float` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Comment: @bjb568 When I use float, it makes the box go to the right or left, but it can't make it go up or down (I need them in the same line) and can you be more specific of how I would use inline-block and write in an answer?

Comment: @Mathias , your solution worked. Thanks! If you would write an answer with it I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @LucasGame13 Great! I added my solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a wrapper around your boxes with `text-align: center` and add `display: inline-block` to the boxes they will align next to each other in the center.

http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/JFkYL/

HTML

```
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box">Content</div>
    <div class="box">Content</div>
    <div class="box">Content</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.boxes {
    text-align: center;
}
/* All the boxes */
.box {
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0 10px;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing absolute positioning. Rule of thumb: Do you need absolute positioning? No.

So, use a float:

```
float: left;
width: 33%;
```

Remember to make the width appropriate so it doesn't fall the the next line. If you don't want to bother thinking about padding/border, use this:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

It makes the border be within the width (instead of just the content).